# Good student edition of Terence?

Tags: resource-request, terence

I'm looking for a good student edition of Terence (any or all of the plays). I have a couple from the 17th or 18th century that are pretty good for my purposes, but I'd love not to have to deal with such unwieldiness. Prior experience with the green and yellow Cambridge Greek and Latin Classics suggests that they'd be slightly more scholarly than I'd like.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tagged this only *terentius* because I couldn't find anything like "editions." If there's something appropriate to add, please let me know and I'll do so.

Comment: Was *just* about to suggest some green & yellows...

Comment: @JoelDerfner You can always create new tags like `editions` or `textbook-recommendations`. They might work well. And there's the old [tag:resource-request].

Comment: I think all the plays are available in the Loeb series.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Added *resource-request* tag.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer That might be where I end up.